# Free APIs for downloading mp3

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, last.fm

I want to develop a windows phone 7 app for commercial use. That will allow me for searching , streaming and Downloading mp3 songs free of cost.
I have studied for the above I would have to create a server that will provide me the music database and different APIs to access that.
I have found one reference [Last.fm](http://www.last.fm/api) and also registered on that but still unable to figure out whether it allows to download songs or not.
Please suggest how to work with it and also if there are any other APIs which would help me out.